# Azure VM SSL certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I have backend https://x-x-x.com hosted in azure portal recently that https has been expired and my task is to replace it with new certificate which is in pkg format.

Now I have been looking around inside Azure Portal for app service but I can only find Azure Resource group which has Virtual Machine has Linux(ubuntu) server and load balancer. After reading documentation I found out that I can do it by connecting to VM and install SSL there using docker and HA proxy. But I am not sure how to do it and if I am on right track or not?

My concern is what is the best way to do it and is there any resource which I can follow to complete my task and will it replace my backend https://x-x-x.com certificate?

Comment: Hi, was the expired certificate purchased from Azure portal directly? Do you have Azure app service or Azure VM?